# How to implement a turnoff switch when using composition (java)?

Tags: java, design-patterns, composition

I have a very simple *Player* class in java that uses some strategies object all inheriting from the interface *PlayerStrategy*.

Some implementations of *PlayerStrategy* are simple but a few others are so resource intensive that I need to make sure I free resources properly when the strategy stops being used. Those strategies have an additional method: turnOff() that takes care of that.

Now if Player leaves the game I'd like it to call turnOff() in all the strategies it has that need it.

The problem is that only a few strategies need turnOff() so I don't feel comfortable adding that method to the *PlayerStrategy* interface. 
Right now when a Player stops playing it checks through reflection if the method turnOff() exists in its strategy. But it's clunky and ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: I would prefer an non-abstract  class with most methods implemented. That way most strategies will be simple, and the heavy ones can over-ride additional methods.

Comment: that's what I usually do but I have a few implementations that implements multiple interfaces which is why I am in the current predicament

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Avoid Reflection:** Reflection is a bad idea. Wherever you can (and it seems you can), avoid it.
2. **It's Good to have `turnOff()` in the Interface:** If you have to use interface... believe me adding `turnOff()` or `cleanup()` method is a good idea; even if most of the subclasses will have just empty curly brackets. You wouldn't need to do extra work if they get updated in future to use some resource that requires a clean up.
3. **You can get What You Want but the Cost is Higher:** If you are really rigid and sure that subclasses wouldn't extend any other class. You may make the `PlayerStrategy` a abstract class with `turnOff()` as empty method. This will solve both your issue, but will limit the subclasses ability to extend other class.

Comment: thank you. I guess it is just easier to add to interface. Purity be damned.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to change your implementations of PlayerStrategy, you can use the [facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) to handle the turnOff.

Comment: so should my facade have turnoff or not?

Comment: @CarrKnight Your façade will have turnoff.